# Require is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, node-modules, netlify

I am trying to write a web application to work with with Tumblr api. I have already used npm and installed both globally and in the file itself: browesrify, tumblr and tumblr.js. whenever I upload the file to my server which runs on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) I get the error that require is undefined.

```
/* global $ document console len alert require */


// Authenticate via OAuth
var tumblr = require('tumblr');
```

Here is my error:

```
script.js:5 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

I am aware of the fact that this question has been asked before and I have gone through all instances of these types of questions and none of the solutions have worked for me so perhaps something has been updated in one or more of the frameworks.

Comment: Wild speculation: You are uploading your raw source files and not the output of browserify. It's really hard to tell given the level of information in the question.

Comment: How would I get and upload the output of browserify instead?

Comment: It's just a file … output to wherever you told browserify to put it.

Comment: Perhaps I am not understanding browserify could you explain further please?

Comment: browserify has a perfectly good website if you want an introduction to it. There is no point in me reproducing it here.

Comment: I am aware of the site and I followed their instructions and still I get the same error.

Comment: Line 5 on which the error occurs coincides with line 5 of the code that you're showing, which would mean that you're not running your script through browserify at all.

Comment: I followed all the steps [here](http://browserify.org/) is there another guide I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Netlify will not have `Browserify` installed on a global scope in npm, so you should set it up in your local project. You set it up using the global install locally, so it works on your local environment.

Make sure you have your `package.json` [setup correctly](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init) and it exists.

Install `browserify` as a development dependency.

```
$ npm install browserify --save-dev
```

Add a build script command to your `package.json`

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "browserify main.js -o bundle.js"
  },
```

**Note** Your command should use the correct browserify command.

Use `npm run build` as your Netlify build command.